# Using getopts to store a filename as an argument

Tags: bash, for-loop

I'm trying to learn to use the getopts() feature in bash to parse my arguments, but my program requires that in addition to my standard -a -b -c type arguments I also need to get any number of files to work on, and I can't find any information on how to make getopts recognize them instead of throwing them out as invalid arguments.  Here's an example:

```shell
while getopts "a:b:c:d" flag
do

    echo Doing: "$flag" $OPTIND $OPTARG

    if [ "$flag" = a ]; then
        first="$OPTARG"
        echo Found argument: $first
    fi
```

... and so on with other if statements.  This works great if my program just needed a command like: program -a -c , but instead I need to take in something like: program -a file.sh -c otherfile.sh.

Can somebody show me an example of how to do something like this?

Comment: I don't get it. You're already doing it. If you call your `program -a file.sh`, you will get the variable `first` assigned with `file.sh`.

Comment: See, this is the problem.  Filenames are meant to be standalone arguments in this script, not arguments to other arguments.  A file should be able to be be input like "script.sh -a4 filename.sh", where "filename.sh" would be detected as its own argument.  Sorry about the lack of clarity.

Comment: Ah. You can't do that with `getopts`. It will stop at the first thing that isn't in its specs. This is pretty much the reason why almost all unix utilities have you write non-option arguments last. For your use case, I'd just use a normal loop over parameters - `getopts` is a bit too smart for what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fragment of a shell script of mine that uses [`getopts`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html) and does more or less as you want to do:

```
arg0=$(basename $0 .sh)

usage()
{
    echo "Usage: $arg0 [-qvF] [-s suffix] -j jdcfile file.msd" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

error()
{
    echo "$arg0: $*" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

Fflag=
suffix=
jdcfile=
qflag=
vflag=no
while getopts Fj:qs:v opt
do
    case "$opt" in
    (F) Fflag="-F";;
    (j) jdcfile="$OPTARG";;
    (q) qflag="-q";;
    (s) suffix="$OPTARG";;
    (v) vflag=yes;;
    (*) usage;;
    esac
done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

case $# in
(1) : OK;;
(*) usage;;
esac

if [ -z "$jdcfile" ]
then error "you did not specify which jdcfile to use (-j option)"
fi

msd_file=$1
```

The `shift` is the part you are missing, I think.  That and the subsequent processing of the remaining arguments on the command line after the `getopts` processing loop.

At the end here in this particular program, there is exactly one file name in `"$@"` that should be processed.  For this particular program, having no files or more than one file listed is an error.  You can remove that final `case` or modify it to suit your needs.  This code also enforces the `-j jdcfile` 'option'; it is a mandatory argument, as shown in the usage message.

A more typical pattern after the `shift` would be:

```
for file in "$@"
do
    ...processing of $file...
done
```

That just leaves you with the zero file name case to deal with.

The `error` and `usage` functions are useful outlines/prototypes too.  As noted in a comment, you can take charge of the error handling if you wish with a leading `:` on the option string.  I choose not to do that, but I'd forgotten that it was a decision I'd made.

Comment: Typically, you want the first character of the argument to `getopts` to be a colon so you can process errors yourself. You would add a `case` for `\?) echo "Unknown option -$OPTARG";;`, `:) echo "Missing option argument for -$OPTARG";;` and `*) echo "Unimplimented option -$OPTARG.";;`. By the way, in your answer in `usage()` you use `$arg0`, but in `error()` you use `$0`.

Comment: Thanks for the bug report on my script.  It turned out to be a prevalent problem; I had to fix 6 scripts in the suite with that one, and one other with similar but slightly more complex issues.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment above - you don't want `getopts` for this. A more simple approach will work:

```
#!/bin/bash

args=()

for arg in "$@"
do
  case "$arg" in
    "-a" )
      echo "We have an '-a'!"
      ;;
    "-b" )
      echo "We have a '-b'!"
      ;;
    * )
      args+=($arg)
  esac
done

echo And we have these arguments: ${args[*]}
```

To see it run:

```
$ ./program one -a two three -b four
We have an '-a'!
We have a '-b'!
And we have these arguments: one two three four
```